# Unable to copy 2015,2016 fields to values property of value of 2015,2016 of respected year

Tags: javascript

I tried to copy 2015,2016 to values property of value of 2015,2016 of respected year

any suggestion?

please refer below snippet

```
let arr = [
          [{2015:10,2016:20,values:[{year: 2015, value: 1},{year: 2016, value: 1}]}],
          [{2015:30,2016:40,values:[{year: 2015, value: 2},{year: 2016, value: 2}]}],
          [{2015:50,2016:60,values:[{year: 2015, value: 3},{year: 2016, value: 3}]}],
          ];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        for(let k=0;k<arr[i][j].values.length;k++) {
          const propName = arr[i][j].values[k].year;
          arr[i][j].values[k].value = arr[i][j][propName];  
        }
      }
    }

let expectedOutput= [
          [{2015:10,2016:20,values:[{year: 2015, value: 10},{year: 2016, value: 20}]}],
          [{2015:30,2016:40,values:[{year: 2015, value: 30},{year: 2016, value: 40}]}],
          [{2015:50,2016:60,values:[{year: 2015, value: 50},{year: 2016, value: 60}]}]
          ];
```

Comment: Please also post the code that you have tried to copy 2015,2016 to values property of value of 2015,2016 of respected year.

Comment: may i know how to access the individual object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Fixed the code...

Straight up answer is:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        for(let k=0;k<arr[i][j].values.length;k++) {
          const propName = arr[i][j].values[k].year;
          arr[i][j].values[k].value = arr[i][j][propName];  
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: do i need add one more loop to handle dynamically

Comment: const propName = arr[i][j].values[i].year;
arr[i][j].values[j].value = arr[i][j][propName]

Comment: add updated answer, dynamically, please refer the question